# Problemas em usar Card-img-overlay com card-columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Estou usando o Bootstrap 4.4 para criar uma coluna de cards:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Problemas em usar Card-img-overlay com card-columns</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="card-columns" style="padding-top: 2%;">

            <!--Inicio cartão-->
            <div class="card">
              <img class="card-img" src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/erondu/1920x1080" style="opacity: 65%;">
              <div class="card-img-overlay">
                <h4 class="card-title">Título do cartão</h4>
                <h6 class="card-subtitle">Subtítulo do cartão</h6>
                <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sapien dui, feugiat et lorem quis, fringilla maximus nisl. Vivamus sed est pulvinar, aliquet purus ut, dictum elit.</p>
                <a class="btn btn-outline-light" href="">Leia mais</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!--Fim do cartão-->
      
            <!--Inicio cartão-->
            <div class="card bg-danger text-white mb-2">
              <div class="card-header">
                Cabeçalho do cartão
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Título do cartão</h4>
                <h6 class="card-subtitle">Subtítulo do cartão</h6>
                <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sapien dui, feugiat et lorem quis, fringilla maximus nisl. Vivamus sed est pulvinar, aliquet purus ut, dictum elit.</p>
                <a class="btn btn-outline-light" href="">Leia mais</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!--Fim do cartão-->
            
            <!--Inicio cartão-->
            <div class="card bg-primary text-white mb-2">
              <div class="card-header">
                Cabeçalho do cartão
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Título do cartão</h4>
                <h6 class="card-subtitle">Subtítulo do cartão</h6>
                <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sapien dui, feugiat et lorem quis, fringilla maximus nisl. Vivamus sed est pulvinar, aliquet purus ut, dictum elit.</p>
                <a class="btn btn-outline-light" href="">Leia mais</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!--Fim do cartão-->
      
            
            <!--Inicio cartão-->
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Título do cartão</h4>
                <h6 class="card-subtitle">Subtítulo do cartão</h6>
                <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sapien dui, feugiat et lorem quis, fringilla maximus nisl. Vivamus sed est pulvinar, aliquet purus ut, dictum elit.</p>
                <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="">Leia mais</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!--Fim do cartão-->
      
            <!--Inicio cartão-->
            <div class="card">
      
              <div class="card-header">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs card-header-tabs">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" href="">Link 1</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="">Link 2</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="">Link 3</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
        
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4>Título do cartão</h4>
                <h6>Subtítulo do cartão</h6>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sapien dui, feugiat et lorem quis, fringilla maximus nisl. Vivamus sed est pulvinar, aliquet purus ut, dictum elit.</p>
                <a class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-block" href="">Leia mais</a>
              </div>
              
            </div>
            <!--Fim do cartão-->
      
      
            <!--Inicio cartão-->
            <div class="card bg-success text-white mb-2">
              <div class="card-header">
                Cabeçalho do cartão
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Título do cartão</h4>
                <h6 class="card-subtitle">Subtítulo do cartão</h6>
                <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sapien dui, feugiat et lorem quis, fringilla maximus nisl. Vivamus sed est pulvinar, aliquet purus ut, dictum elit.</p>
                <a class="btn btn-outline-success" href="">Leia mais</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!--Fim do cartão-->
      
          </div>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

O problema se da no carde em que faço uso do Card-img-overlay. Quando a tela tem uma resolução maior a exibição ocorre como esperado:

[image: Funcionando corretamente]

Já quando a tela é menor:

[image: Parte do carte omitido e imagem não se ajusta]

Parte do carde e do conteúdo dele são omitidas. Tentei da padding mas não funcionou te forma adequada.

Além disso não consigo fazer com que a imagem se adeque. Tentei por uma imagem verticalmente maior mas tudo q consigo é que o card ocupe o espaço correspondente a altura da imagem.

Como fazer com que o conteúdo não seja sobreposto por outro card ? e pra que a imagem ocupe todo espaço do card sempre ?

Comment: Cara vc usou algum CSS extra, tipo fez algum CSS na mão ou está usando tudo original do Bootstrap?

Comment: Tudo original do Bootstrap

Comment: Pq do voto negativo ? Como posso melhorar a questão ?

Comment: Nem foi meu o voto ok, mas quase toda pergunta de CSS leva voto negativo, na faz um tempo que venho reparando isso

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia, fiz uma adaptação simples para funcionar corretamente.

Primeiro, eu removi a tag  que você estava utilizando para trazer a imagem, e criei a classe *card-bg* para chamar no arquivo *css*.

```
<div class="card card-bg">
                <h4 class="card-title">Título do cartão</h4>
                <h6 class="card-subtitle">Subtítulo do cartão</h6>
                <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sapien dui, feugiat et lorem quis, fringilla maximus nisl. Vivamus sed est pulvinar, aliquet purus ut, dictum elit.</p>
                <a class="btn btn-outline-light" href="">Leia mais</a>
</div>
```

E depois eu trouxe a imagem como *background* da sua  utilizando CSS.

```
.card-bg {
     background: url('https://source.unsplash.com/user/erondu/1920x1080') fixed;
     /* O 'fixed' NÃO É OBRIGATÓRIO! */
}
```

Você pode aplicar outras propriedades a esse background, caso tenha interesse e haja necessidade, mas dessa maneira já funciona da maneira que você citou.

Espero que tenha ajudado.

Comment: Cara ele está usando Bootstrap e vc destruiu a estrutura do Card tirando as tags https://prnt.sc/qxegrq, além disso se ele tiver 10 card ele vai ter que fazer 10 classes no CSS cada uma. com uma imagem, e para piorar imagem de background não aparece em impressão e tb não é acessível para leitores de tela, não tem alt etc